# REST API optional path elements

Tags: api, rest

I am in the process of designing a new API and am trying to make it as simple as possible. For the intended system most API consumers will be referencing objects that belong to them alone however a few other accounts will "own" objects in other peoples accounts. The questions is whether account becomes a required part of the path or an optional inclusion for these special super-accounts.

Here is an example spec and works fine in the single user context (Account ID "basic1"):

```
# return person "s4t4s2" for account "basic1"
GET /v1/person/s4t4s2 
# return team "g3a35a" for account "basic1"
GET /v1/team/g3a35a
```

For super-accounts they have their own objects where the above implementation works, however they also require access to the properties of accounts they effectively own (Account ID "super1"):

```
# return person "s4t4s2" for account "super1"
GET /v1/person/s4t4s2 
# get team "g399a2" for account "super1"
GET /v1/team/g399a2 
# return person "s4t4s2" for account "basic1"
GET /v1/accounts/basic1/person/s4t4s2
```

Because most of my consumers will be dealing with the single account view is it best practice to use the second format for all accounts or is it entirely valid to use both formats with automatic scoping via authentication credientials when the account is omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, those are the same "person" resources, but they have multiple URIs? I would probably prefer having one URI for a single instance of a resource. Even if it has different "views". Different views can still be solved by either having different `media-type`s, or just filling out fields differently on the same `media-type` depending on the user's permissions.

The advantage of having a single URI for a single instance is that it can be bookmarked, cached, etc. For example if a user's team/account view changes, it can't reuse its links to persons because the URIs change. I think that is not a good design.

If my understanding is wrong, and `/v1/accounts/basic1/person/s4t4s2` is not the same person as `/v1/person/s4t4s2` then disregard my comment. :)

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your time. You are correct that those URI's refer to the same user. If I have understood your comment correctly I believe you are saying that using an implied account ID path is not actually beneficial to anyone as it disrupts the commonality. Essentially a person always belongs to an account so we should make that clear in the path? Your mention of "media-type" is just a statement that this decision won't impact the content types we are able to respond with? If not please let me know if i'm missing something useful :) Thanks again

Comment: I don't know your use-case and domain in detail, but I would think that a "person" exists independently of an account. Can a person switch accounts? Or have multiple accounts? In other words, is the account really part of the *identity* of a person? I think in most cases it is not, therefore it should not be part of the URI.

Comment: Ah I see, its more of a reseller type of scenario - most accounts aren't resellers but those who are have control over other accounts if that makes sense. A person would only ever exist in a single account.